# Solved exercises of manifold theory

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, tensors

I am currently reading the book "Semi-Riemannian geometry with applications to relativity" by Barret O'Neill, and I am trying to do the exercises suggested at the end of each chapter, as I find this the best way to really understand the mathematics behind.

The aim of most exercises is to prove a statement. For example (Ex 13 Chapter 1)

For a function $f\in\mathcal{F}(M)$ its differential $df:T(M)\rightarrow\mathbb{M}$ and its differential map $df:T(M)\rightarrow T(\mathbb{R}^1)$ differ only by a canonical isomorphism.

I find myself a little bit lost when trying to solve these kind of problems as often I do not know how to start. I would like to find a book with similar exercises and with the solutions explained (manifold theory, tensors, and semi-riemannian manifold and submanifolds, just as the first 4 chapters of O'Neills book). I hope once I understand some exercises, I will be able to do the rest on my own

Comment: Definitions are king! The simplest and most-important to get done and right straight away are those which are simply definition-unwinding. The question you quote comes under this category, and the only person who can really help is yourself, because if you can’t answer it, it means you haven’t understood the definitions in the chapter, or you’re not even understanding the question statement itself (which means you haven’t understood the definitions of the various objects in the problem… i.e you need to reread the section). Seeing as O’Neill’s writing is very clear, it means you should reread.

Comment: Looking at the "Related" sidebar next to this question, the particular exercise you're mentioning has been already covered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3143878/the-differential-dftm-rightarrow-mathbbr-and-the-differential-map-dftm

Comment: there are of course other types of questions, but some of them can be solved by definition-chasing and learning to compute using the definitions. Beyond that, of course, one just needs to practice. Having said all that, two books I know which include answers (atleast for some questions) are Godinho-Natario, and Amol-Sasane. They certainly don’t cover everything O’Neill does but should hopefully get you started. But really, for many of the questions, you need to develop the skill of understanding definitions (time-consuming in my experience) and using them to prove/compute things.